Laravel Sanctum gives me 401 error despite using XSRF-TOKEN and cookies
I'm trying to configure Laravel Sanctum to create sessions with a user after my Sign In with Google endpoint verifies their JWT. I keep getting a 401 error with every endpoint that uses auth:sanctum as the middleware after the user has logged in and gotten the XSRF-TOKEN and api_session cookies.
Note: I'm using Laravel as my backend and React as my SPA frontend (no rendering is done for my site with Laravel, except for the occasional test page).
I tried setting all of the correct domain settings and requesting the XSRF-TOKEN before using any endpoint after signing in with Google, but I keep getting a 401 error saying "Unauthenticated". I checked the cookies tab and made some changes to make SameSite=None and Secure=true, which then made the cookies set properly but I'm still getting a 401 error. I run this Laravel app on api.speedcartapp.com via an nginx reverse proxy that runs on port 8443, but I run my React app (at least for testing, right now) on localhost:3000 (on production, it's www.speedcartapp.com). I have HTTPS configured for both my backend and frontend deployments (I haven't deployed my frontend yet, still testing, but I have my Laravel backend deployed to test it).
If you need to see any files, the following text includes all relevant files in this setup.
Here's one of the fetch calls I have in my React code that calls a Laravel endpoint using auth:sanctum as middleware (see I should have all headers set):
import { BASE_URL } from '@constants/config';

export const fetchOwnedShoppingLists = () => {
    return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/shopping-lists`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include' // Include cookies in the request
    });
};

Here are my relevant environment variables for Laravel Sanctum:
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,localhost:3000,.speedcartapp.com
SESSION_DOMAIN=.speedcartapp.com
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/

This is my cors.php file:
<?php

// config/cors.php

return [

    'paths' => ['*'],  // Allow all paths
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000', 'https://www.speedcartapp.com', 'https://speedcartapp.com'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,

];

Here's my sanctum.php file:
<?php

use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,.speedcartapp.com',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. This will override any values set in the token's
    | "expires_at" attribute, but first-party sessions are not affected.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => 525600,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Token Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Sanctum can prefix new tokens in order to take advantage of numerous
    | security scanning initiatives maintained by open source platforms
    | that notify developers if they commit tokens into repositories.
    |
    | See: https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/secret-scanning/about-secret-scanning
    |
    */

    'token_prefix' => env('SANCTUM_TOKEN_PREFIX', ''),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'authenticate_session' => Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        'validate_csrf_token' => Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidateCsrfToken::class,
    ],

];

Here's my session.php file:
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines the default session driver that is utilized for
    | incoming requests. Laravel supports a variety of storage options to
    | persist session data. Database storage is a great default choice.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to expire immediately when the browser is closed then you may
    | indicate that via the expire_on_close configuration option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => env('SESSION_EXPIRE_ON_CLOSE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it's stored. All encryption is performed
    | automatically by Laravel and you may use the session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => env('SESSION_ENCRYPT', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing the "file" session driver, the session files are placed
    | on disk. The default storage location is defined here; however, you
    | are free to provide another location where they should be stored.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table to
    | be used to store sessions. Of course, a sensible default is defined
    | for you; however, you're welcome to change this to another table.
    |
    */

    'table' => env('SESSION_TABLE', 'sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using one of the framework's cache driven session backends, you may
    | define the cache store which should be used to store the session data
    | between requests. This must match one of your defined cache stores.
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the session cookie that is created by
    | the framework. Typically, you should not need to change this value
    | since doing so does not grant a meaningful security improvement.
    |
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application, but you're free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => env('SESSION_PATH', '/'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the domain and subdomains the session cookie is
    | available to. By default, the cookie will be available to the root
    | domain and all subdomains. Typically, this shouldn't be changed.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'speedcartapp.com'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. It's unlikely you should disable this option.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => env('SESSION_HTTP_ONLY', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" to permit secure cross-site requests.
    |
    | See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => env('SESSION_SAME_SITE', "none"),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Partitioned Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will tie the cookie to the top-level site for
    | a cross-site context. Partitioned cookies are accepted by the browser
    | when flagged "secure" and the Same-Site attribute is set to "none".
    |
    */

    'partitioned' => env('SESSION_PARTITIONED_COOKIE', false),

];

Lastly, here is my app.php file:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
            '*',
        ]);
        $middleware->statefulApi();
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

